# Efficient Down-sampling in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a database where I store a lot of data and generate views for graphs. Instead of returning all of the data for the graph, I return only a predefined number of samples. The way I currently do this is using a map/reduce job on mongo, but I don't know if the way I am doing this is very efficient, it takes 14 seconds and pegs the CPU on on graph that has over 89000 samples for example.

The down sampling works by calculating a "resolution", i.e. (total # of points) / (desired # of samples). It then keeps and external count and index using scope variables. It then basically looks at each point and decides whether to include it in the results list based on the resolution and the current state of the count/index variables.

This works fine, but is pretty slow and probably not scalable. I am wondering if it would be better for example to just return all of the points and do the down sampling in ruby, or maybe there is an even better way.

Comment: Check out the new aggregation framework for Mongo. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/ You can do aggregations (obviously) and it's much, much faster than map/reduce.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure I can get aggregations to work in this case. Right now I am downsampling based on the offset of the document in an array after sorting. I am thinking a better way to do it though would be by the value x in the document. For example, I have data from x = 10,000 to x = 100,000,000 with 100,000 data points. I want to downsample this to only 1,000 points, evenly spaced throughout the domain of x (10,000 - 1,000,000). What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: So you have 100k elements in an array in a document?

Comment: To clarify, I didn't mean an array. I meant, I order by my x value, and my downsampling works by using the index of the returned documents.

Comment: you sort the points and then how do you use offset to downsample?  every Nth point?

Comment: Almost, but a bit more tricky since the ratio is not usually an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Case anyone is interested, this is the solution I came up with. It took me a while to figure out due to some limitations of mongodb, but it works pretty well and is as much as 10x faster than my current map reduce solution.

Here is the aggregation code:

```
db.data.aggregate(
  {$match: {$and: [{graph_id: gid}, {"x.value": {$gt: start, $lt: stop}}]}},
  {$project: {x: 1, y: 1, series: 1, chunk: {$subtract: [{$divide: ["$x.value", step]}, {$mod: [{$divide: ["$x.value", step]}, 1]}]}}},
  {$group: {
    _id: {
      chunk: "$chunk",
      series: "$series"
    },
    series: {$first: "$series"},
    x: {$first: "$x"},
    y: {$first: "$y"},
    }
  },
  {$sort: {"x.value": 1}}
)
```

This solution chunks the data. I wanted to do something like int(x.value / step), but mongodb does not have integer math operators. So I had to fake it with ((x.value/step) - ((x.value/step) % 1)) which gives you the integer part of division.

This works well and would allow you to do things like average the chunks instead of just choosing the first, pretty easily.